# Dynamically get class name and reference?

Tags: java, class, reflection, jackson

I have a line of code where I am converting my `Object` to POJO. I am using jackson library for this.

```
POJO container = objectMapper.convertValue(resource, POJO.class);
```

Now I have to do this for many (~50) POJOs. So instead of writing so many switch cases, I wanted to do it in one line dynamically. I have a enum from where I will get my POJO name.

Is there a easy way to achieve this. I searched and got an idea that `Class.forName` shall be used. I will get POJO.class from there. How to get reference to POJO dynamically?

Comment: You need to know what you're converting the JSON into, so unless you can write something that determines object types by a unique combination of fields (or you have something in the JSON that correlates directly to your Java code) you're going to have to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is you can directly convert to some Class, but you can't guess what class: you must have this information in your data also

1 specify the format of your data, and embed the name of the class inside

Example:

```
 {"classname":"MyClass","object":  ["var1": 1, "var2":33,"var3":"some string","var4":true] }
```

2 read your data as "classical JSON object", to get classname, and the "rest of it" (object)

3 now you have your class name: you can convert "object" to what you want.